# Field of definition for isomorphism classes of modular representations

Tags: reference-request, modular-representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $\sigma: G \to GL_n(k)$ be a (not necessarily irreducible) representation defined over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p$. Let $\sigma^{(m)}$ denote the mth frobenius twist of $\sigma$, that is $\sigma_{ij}^{(m)}(g) = (\sigma_{ij}(g))^{p^m}$. Note that if $\sigma^{(m)} = \sigma$ then the image of $\sigma$ lands inside $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_{p^m})$.

Here are two notions:

1. If $\sigma$ is isomorphic to (i.e. conjugate to) a representation $\tilde{\sigma}$ such that $\tilde{\sigma}^{(m)} = \tilde{\sigma}$, then I would say "$\sigma$ is defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$".
2. If instead we only know that $\sigma^{(m)}$ and $\sigma$ are isomorphic, it seems natural to say that "the isomorphism class of $\sigma$ is defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$".

My first question is: Are these actually different notions? My gut says yes, but I couldn't come up with a counterexample this afternoon.

If the answer is yes, my follow up is:  Is there a reference for working with this second notion of the field of definition of an isomorphism class of representations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two notions are the same.

Clearly the first implies the second.

Assume that $\sigma^{(m)}$ is isomorphic to $\sigma$. So there is some $a\in GL_n(k)$ such that $a\sigma^{(m)}(g)a^{-1}=\sigma(g)$ for all $g\in G$.

By [Lang's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lang%27s_theorem), there is some $b\in GL_n(k)$ with $a=b^{-1}b^{(m)}$. Then $b^{(m)}\sigma^{(m)}(g)(b^{(m)})^{-1}=b\sigma(g)b^{-1}$. So the representation $\tilde{\sigma}=b\sigma b^{-1}$, which is conjugate to $\sigma$, satisfies $\tilde{\sigma}^{(m)}=\tilde{\sigma}$.